# Gmail Gives HTML5 Canvas Warning!

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I am new using Tor Browser Bundle.  Before, I never noticed Gmail tries to use the HTML5 canvas. (Tor Browser warns this when logging into Gmail.)  What do they want to do with the canvas?

Comment: Interesting, I can't find the canvas any where in Gmail source. I'm not using Tor though. I don't think not allowing the canvas will restrict any functionality of Gmail, so don't allow the HTML5 Canvas as it only allows for the possibility of security vulnerabilities.

Comment: I have no real information on the matter, but I assume it's for tracking. Canvas objects are quite commonly used for browser fingerprinting by ad networks as an alternative to cookies, but this doesn't really have anything to do with Tor (other than the fact that you happened to be using TBB at the time).